# Time-consuming of the definition of two-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, time, initialization

I want define a two-dimensional array of size [545 333][116 109] and the next part of the code that initializes
I use the following code

```
w1, h1 = 545333, 116109
X = [[0 for x1 in range (w1)] for y1 in range (h1)]
while (i <116109):
 ###### other code...........
     j = 0
     while (j <545333):
         if allfeature [j] not in eachfeature:
             X [i] [j] = 0
         else:
             X [i] [j] = 1
         j = j + 1
     i=i+1
```

But the problem is the high time and low speed.
What code do you recommend?

Comment: What's `eachfeature`? Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: If it's Python 2, you have issues with `range`...

Comment: Not to mention the fact that if you store all the values, even at a byte each, you're getting 50 gigs of stuff.

Comment: So to sum it up, what could you possibly be doing with something this large?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary eachfeature is a list....

Comment: pycharm 2016  and python 3.5

Comment: Iluvatar has under-counted: your 2D list contains 63,318,069,297 items. Even on 32 bit Python, that's 253,272,277,188 bytes just for the pointers to the list items, and then there's the actual storage required for the items themselves. Do you have that much RAM? :)

Comment: You might need a sparse data structure. See what [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) has to offer: [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/sparse.html). However, it depends upon what you want to do with the data. Why do you need it all in memory at the same time?

Comment: The rest of the code no problem, just the part that is time-consuming :` X = [[0 for x1 in range (w1)] for y1 in range (h1)]  `

Comment: The rest of the code might be no problem, but algorithms and data structures are tightly dependent. What are you doing that requires such massive resources? As your choice of data structure is likely to be wrong, so too is your choice of algorithm.

Comment: @PM2Ring my RAM=6G.  I need this large array  because I'm working with sklearn
What code do you recommend?

Comment: @PeterWood I'm working with sklearn .the array is for feature vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW,

```
X = [[0] * w1 for y1 in range (h1)]
```

is faster than

```
X = [[0 for x1 in range (w1)] for y1 in range (h1)]
```

and produces identical results. But with `w1, h1 = 545333, 116109` you don't have enough RAM to create that list.

A better option is to make X a set of tuples, you *may* have enough RAM for that, if `allfeature[j] in eachfeature` is only true for a small number of the `j` values in `range(w1)`.

Here's a short demo:

```
w1, h1 = 545333, 116109
X = set()
for j in range(w1):
    if allfeature[j] in eachfeature:
        for i in range(h1):
            X.add((i, j))
```

However, even that uses quite a lot of RAM, due to the size of `h1`. As  Peter Wood says, there may be a better way to organize the data and logic of your code.

---

The code you posted in your answer doesn't do what you want. But even if you did have enough RAM to create that list it wouldn't contain the data you want because all the inner lists are actually the same list.

Here's a small demo of that behaviour:

```
x = []
x1 = [0, 9]
for i in range(5):
    x1[0] = i
    x.append(x1)
print(x)
```

**output**

```
[[4, 9], [4, 9], [4, 9], [4, 9], [4, 9]]
```

Instead, you need to append *copies* of `x1`, like this:

```
x = []
x1 = [0, 9]
for i in range(5):
    x1[0] = i
    x.append(x1[:])
print(x)
```

**output**

```
[[0, 9], [1, 9], [2, 9], [3, 9], [4, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Please also see the code below and compare with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way

```
w1= 545333
X1 = [0 for x1 in range(w1)]
X=[]
while(i<116109):
    ..........

    while(j<545333):
        if allfeature[j] in eachfeature:
            X1[j]=1
        j=j+1

    X.append(X1)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to create a 2D array.

Comment: @roganjosh oh,yes. X=X+X1 >>> X.append(X1)

Comment: This doesn't do what you want, and it still uses too much RAM. Your outer loop puts 116109 references to the same `X1` list into `X`.